# Como accedo a un componente de angular mediante un link directo y no por routerlink?

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema y seria genial si me pudiesen ayudar a solucionarlo. Es acerca del routing del angular.

Tengo el siguiente routing:

Esto se traduce en un componente main, uno de content y despues billing y collection.

billing y collection se cargan dentro de content y content dentro de main.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'main' },
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainPageComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '' },
      {
        path: '',
        component: ContentPageComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'billing' },
          { path: 'billing', component: BillingComponent },
          { path: 'collection', component: CollectionComponent }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Si yo cargo la ruta localhost:4200 me redirecciona inmediatamente a localhost:4200/main/billing.

Ahora, si quiero ingresar a la pagina de collection, solo puedo hacerlo mediante un boton [routerLink] =['/main', 'collection'].

Lo mismo ocurre para billing.

El enrutamiento funciona bien de ese modo, pero si yo quiero acceder a una de esas dos pantallas con el link directo, es decir localhost:4200/main/collection o localhost:4200/main/billing, se redirecciona a la raiz por defecto.

Me es imposible acceder escribiendo la ruta en el navegador, solo puedo acceder con routerLink.

Como puedo habilitar para poder acceder directamente?. Esto es por que ese link tendra que ser puesto en un menu de otro sistema y no me sirve ingresar a la pagina sin tener definido donde ir previamente.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el orden de las rutas, que vayan de las más específicas a las más genéricas:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainPageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ContentPageComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'billing', component: BillingComponent },
          { path: 'collection', component: CollectionComponent },
          { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'billing' },
        ]
      },
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '' },
    ]
  },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'main' },
];
```

Comment: Gracias Lobos, intente con la solucion que propusiste, pero es imposible, a pesar de todo, al momento de querer acceder directamente a collection, se regresa al default main/billing, pero no ingresa a main/collection.

He intentado con varias alternativas y la unica que hace dicha funcion, es usando botones de RouterLink